# Compositing managers

Tags: 12.10, compositing

How can I determine which compositor is currently being used when multiple desktops have been installed such as LXDE and XFCE. Compiz is also installed.

Is there a code that will show which installed compositing manager being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct command to get your current compositing manager. To do that, we need to make a list of them and check in the current processes. I made a script for this. Here it goes:

```
#!/bin/sh

COMPOSITORS=('awesome' 'beryl' 'blackbox' 'compiz' 'dwm' 'enlightenment' 'fluxbox' 'fvwm' 'i3' 'icewm' 'kwin' 'metacity' 'musca' 'openbox' 'pekwm' 'ratpoison' 'scrotwm' 'wmaker' 'wmfs' 'wmii' 'xfwm4' 'xmonad')

for i in `ps -u $USER -o comm`; do
    for c in ${COMPOSITORS[@]}; do
        if [ "$i" == "$c" ]; then
            echo "Your compositor is $i"
        fi
    done
done
```

Open your editor, paste the code above and save it with the name **check-compositor.sh**. Then open the terminal and execute 
`$ sh path/to/your/file/check-compositor.sh`
That should show your current compositor manager. You can add more compositing managers to the list if you wish, but I think that's pretty much all of them.

Comment: script fails to run using suggested!! Free Replay, Try Again

Comment: You could add `xcompmgr`, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#How_to_control_window_opacity), since OP is interested in LXDE. Also, I'm not sure about including Openbox. To my mind, it's a window manager. (I don't use compositing myself and am not familiar with the other names in the list.)

Comment: @Ringtail, what do you have in `autostart`?

Comment: @vasa1 nothing in .config/autostart for a comp-manager

Comment: do you have something like `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`? I know you haven't said you're using Lubuntu (or ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart)?

Comment: @Ringtail what compositor and desktop environment were you using when you ran the script? I tested the script in Unity, Xfce and Openbox with a few compositors in the script list and worked properly in all of them.

Comment: @Jesse USING XFCE

Comment: @Ringtail Does the script output some error or it just doesn't display anything?

Comment: @Jesse no output, no display using this method, however using an open terminal with just the code I am able to return the expected. The CODE DOES work, thanks

Comment: Your list of compositors is wrong. Where did you get it from? OpenBox is not compositing (but listed), while xcompmgr is a compositing manager (not listed). – You know the difference between window and compositing manager?

Comment: This command gives me nothing on a new Ubuntu 18.04 install. Add `gnome-shell` since I think in 18.04 it includes mutter?